# Server 2016 - Backup 517 error

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-backup

For the last week one server is failing backups to a NAS with

```
The backup operation that started at '‎2017‎-‎12‎-‎17T23:37:47.558318200Z' has failed with following error code '0x807800C5' (There was a failure in preparing the backup image of one of the volumes in the backup set.). Please review the event details for a solution, and then rerun the backup operation once the issue is resolved.
```

It creates the shadow copy, backs up the EFI partition, moves on to backing up the C: drive and then fails

[image: Backup_Image]

Other servers, plus a whole raft of Sybase databases backup to the same NAS without any problems

I changed WindowsImageBackup to a different name. It created the directory but still fails, getting only as far as

[image: Drive_Image_One]

This Saturday (after patch Tuesday) it was rebooted, but still the same. At a loss with this one!

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you aren't the only one: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/f965a05b-a875-408d-8398-33b445437c97/windows-2016-backup-fails-event-id-517-error-code-0x807800c5?forum=windowsbackup

Comment: I too also tried TechNet at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/02d84586-e275-4951-bba8-fd25ba19b590/server-2016-windows-backup-fails-with-error-code-0x807800c5-2155348165?forum=winservergen - since then another server has started with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Stumped by the same problem on my VM 2016 Server where the following error entries on the BU job in the web admin GUI:
[image]
wbadmin GUI Backup listed errors

In my case, I resolved the issue by:

1. Deleting the existing scheduled Job
2. Opened the Config Settings:
   [image]
   (Right mouse click 'Local Backup') and changed from 'Faster Backup Performance' to 'Normal':
   [image]
3. Executing a backup once a job that did not point to a sub directory as shown in the first image above.

The job was executed successfully.

Afterwhich I then created a scheduled job & executed it once to confirm functionality.

Perhaps, this may help some of you guys out.